# Android RecycleView Add SearchView programmatically

Tags: android, search, filter, android-recyclerview

I am designing RecycleView programmatically without using XML, So I can reuse this code in all projects by just coping the Java file.

I need to add SearchView to the RecycleView and set all search query filters programmatically without using any third party API.

```
SearchView searchVyuVar = new SearchView(this);
searchVyuVar.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
    {
        recylcleLysLysMgrVar.filter(query);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        recylcleLysLysMgrVar.filter(newText);
        return true;
    }
});

RecyclerView recylcleLysLyoVav = new RecyclerView(this);
recylcleLysLyoVav.addView(searchVyuVar);

recylcleLysLyoVav.setAdapter(recylcleLysLysMgrVar);
recylcleLysLyoVav.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After One full day of struggle I got this Search Bar designed programatically.
With the help of below link
http://abhiandroid.com/ui/searchview

This is to help all whom I wish not to struggle like me.

```
LinearLayout NamSupRloVav;
SearchView NamSrhVyuVav;
RecyclerView NamLysLyoVav;
NamLysAdrCls NamLysAdrVar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    NamSupRloVav = new LinearLayout(this);
    NamSupRloVav.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    NamSrhVyuVav = new SearchView(this);
    NamSrhVyuVav.setQueryHint("Search . . .");
    NamSrhVyuVav.setIconified(false);
    NamSrhVyuVav.onActionViewExpanded();
    NamSrhVyuVav.setPadding(20,10,20,10);
    NamSupRloVav.addView(NamSrhVyuVav);

    NamLysLyoVav = new RecyclerView(this);
    NamLysLyoVav.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    NamLysLyoVav.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

    NamLysAdrVar = new NamLysAdrCls(GetAllNamAryLysFnc());
    NamLysLyoVav.setAdapter(NamLysAdrVar);
    NamLysLyoVav.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    NamSrhVyuVav.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String SrhSrgPsgVal)
        {
            NamLysAdrVar.SrhFltFnc(SrhSrgPsgVal);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String SrhSrgPsgVal)
        {
            NamLysAdrVar.SrhFltFnc(SrhSrgPsgVal);
            return true;
        }
    });

    NamSupRloVav.addView(NamLysLyoVav);
    setContentView(NamSupRloVav);
}

public class NamLysAdrCls extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VyuHlrCls>
{
    ArrayList<NamCls> FchNamAryLysVar = new ArrayList<NamCls>();
    ArrayList<NamCls> SrhNamAryLysVar = new ArrayList<NamCls>();

    public NamLysAdrCls(ArrayList<NamCls> NamLysPsgVar)
    {
        FchNamAryLysVar.addAll(NamLysPsgVar);
        SrhNamAryLysVar.addAll(NamLysPsgVar);
    }

    @Override
    public VyuHlrCls onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup HubVyuGrp, int viewType)
    {
// |=> CodTdo Design Itm Idx Lyo
        VyuHlrCls VyuHlrVar = new VyuHlrCls(NamLysItmLloVav);
        return VyuHlrVar;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VyuHlrCls VyuHlrPsgVar, int ItmIdxPsgVar)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return SrhNamAryLysVar.size();
    }

    public void DelItmFnc(int ItmPosPsgVar)
    {
        SrhNamAryLysVar.remove(ItmPosPsgVar);
        notifyItemRemoved(ItmPosPsgVar);
    }

    public void SrhFltFnc(String SrhSrgPsgVal)
    {
        SrhSrgPsgVal = SrhSrgPsgVal.toLowerCase();
        SrhNamAryLysVar.clear();
        if (SrhSrgPsgVal.length() == 0) SrhNamAryLysVar.addAll(FchNamAryLysVar);
        else
        {
            for (NamCls NamIdxVar : FchNamAryLysVar)
            {
                if(NamIdxVar.toLowerCase().contains(SrhSrgPsgVal))
                {
                    SrhNamAryLysVar.add(NamIdxVar);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly Ignore the diff form of naming the functions and variables used.